# WPF button background image with transparency

Tags: wpf, xaml, button, transparency

I have a WPF button
I want to add the button an image background
The image is a PNG with transparency
here is what I have:

```
<Button
    Width="160"
    Height="55"
    BorderThickness="0">
      <Button.Background>
           <ImageBrush ImageSource="C:\images\mute.png" />
      </Button.Background>
                      Mute
</Button>
```

How do i set the background to allow transparency?

Comment: Not sure whether it's a typo, but your question says the image is a `png`, and the code says otherwise... What is the image? `jpg` or `png`?

Comment: @GeoffJames its png. I fixed it

Answer (score 2):

your button control should be like that:

```
 <Button Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent" >
                            <ContentControl>
                                <Image Width="160"
                                 Height="55" Source="C:\images\mute.jpg"  />
                            </ContentControl>
                             Mute
                        </Button>
```

Comment: in this way the image alignment is not perfect (some of it is hidden and another issue is the content. it should hold the text "Mute"

Comment: can you check my edits? you can control height and width as you like and give the button a text :)

Comment: any updates ? I tried my solution and it worked fine with me :)

Comment: when i am adding the "mute" text i am getting an error: The property 'Content' is set more than once.